# Does Azure Functions run NPM install on cold starts?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function set up to handle some logging to a database for me. The only dependency I have in my project is the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package and the function is ~70 lines of code and basically just takes the request and maps it to the database.

I'm experiencing extreme response times on some requests, up to 3 minutes! My spontaneous thought is that it's because it has to run npm install every time it starts a new instance of the function (cold starts).

Is this correct? What can I do to reduce the latency? Will it help to bundle mssql using WebPack in a build step and publish the bundled js to Azure?

[image: Server response time]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known behavior (called cold start) when you are using the Consumption plan on your functions. An example of the same issue [reported here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/298).

What you can do to mitigate this issue, in case you do not want to face the cold start, you can use the Premium Plan (it is still a Pay-as-you-Go pricing model). More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/).

Comment: Right. So it does run npm install on cold starts then?

Comment: Yes, it runs npm install for packages that are not available.

Comment: Also, please do not create mechanisms to pre-warm your functions. That was a workaround created when we did not have the Premium Plan available, but now with the Premium Plan available, it provides you a pre-warmed instance all the time

Comment: I have a "keep-alive function" that sends a ping request to my main function. Should I remove this?

Comment: Yes, please don't do that @mottosson. That's against the Consumption model. Think with me. Consumption model is meant for you to pay for what you consume, and in this case for functions, for the amount of executions and resources consumed. So, if you have something pinging your function, the amount of executions are increasing, so eventually you will pay anyway. So i would recommend you to follow the best practices and use the Premium Plan as i mentioned on my answer. Link there available.

Comment: I agree! I think if I bundle my dependencies the request time will go down significantly and I won't even need a keep-alive. 0-10 seconds response time is no problem in this use case. Thank you!

Comment: That's the way to go. Another important detail, this is a discussion I had several times with other people. If you are using Windows environment on your function apps, you will have .NET framework and .NET Core preinstalled, whatever VM you are using, and consequently most of the packages you may use in your c# code will be available there, so no need to install package during function's cold start, so that's another way to reduce significatly the cold start by using c# and .NET (framework or core) instead of open-source technologies such as node, etc. But if you need node, then use node. :)

Comment: I forgot about .net for a second. That's definitely an option! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the packages, It will not install. If it not available, it will install. I think this is cold start.

Have a look of [this doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/).

Use app service plan can avoid this.

Also you can also pre-warmed the function to avoid this problem. Have a look of [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#pre-warmed-instances).

Comment: Does it run npm install on cold starts? Would I benefit from building my project with WebPack and publish the bundle to avoid npm install on cold starts?

Comment: @mottosson Yes, you are right. Bundle your node modules with WebPack is a good choose. It can reduce your cold start time. But to avoid cold start, I advice you to pre-warm the function or use app service plan.

Comment: @mottosson Consumption model is made to allow your code to run in different environments (VMs). So, in case it does not have the package available, it needs to install it.

Comment: Also, don't pre-warm the function, neither use an app service plan, i would say. App service plan is a different model, where you preallocate resources to be used by your functions. So you lose the benefit of cost-efficiency that you have using the Consumption plan. In case you want a pre-warmed instance, use the Premium Plan